# Visual Studio post-build event fails to run powershell script (blocked by group policy)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, post-build-event, group-policy

When I want to execute powershell script from **non-admin** Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (Win 7):

[image]

it seems to be blocked by the group policy settings (result from output window):

```
1>  This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your ...
```

If my Visual Studio runs in **admin** mode, everything works.

The thing is, powershell setup seems to be **the same** in both admin and non-admin modes:

[image]

32bit versions:

[image]

I've also tried to bypass the policy directly:

[image]

and even tried to put the execution policy setup inside the *test.ps1* script itself:

[image]

Nothing helps (mixed versions used) - group policy blocks the powershell.

How to understand what's going on and possibly fix it?

Comment: Can you open PowerShell and run a script from the PowerShell prompt?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Yes, I can (both admin and non-admin PS console).

Comment: I would ask whoever manages your Group Policy settings.